# Why here using -1,1,0 in this logic?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

```
Collections.sort(al,(s1,s2)->{

            return s1.id<s2.id?-1:s1.id>s2.id?1:s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:0;
        });
```

Why here using -1,1,0 in this logic could you please tell me

Comment: Look at the [Comparator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and then check the arguments being sent to [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: This is how Comparator works.

With passed two objects,

if object1 > object2 then it should return positive, so simply returning positive number 1 is good enough. One can return any positive number like 2, 3 or 1000.

Similarly, if object1 < object2 then it should return negative so simply return -1. Or you can return -2 -5 or -1000.

And in case both objects are same, return zero to signify that there is no difference between them.

Based upon the value returned, comparator arranges them in either ascending or descending order.

Comment: @  Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi  Thankyou now i understood

Comment: Note, that this comparator implementation is wrong in the case that s1.id = s2.id. The comparison of the `marks` field in this case can never lead to a `1` result. You may conclude that  s1 < s2 but at the same time not s2 > s1.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite this

```
return s1.id<s2.id?-1:s1.id>s2.id?1:s1.marks>s2.marks?-1:0;
```

To this code bellow to more easily understand

```
if (s1.id < s2.id)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    if (s1.id > s2.id)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (s1.marks>s2.marks)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

About -1, 0, 1, read [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument
>   is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.